# BootStrap Navbar-Toggle Not Working In asp.net Using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed nuget package then I installed bootstrap. Now I have folders

```
Contents
 containing bootstrap css files 
Scripts 
 containing .js files
```

In header of Master Page I have included it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Then I tried to make nav like

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

But error is attribute data toggle is not a valid attribute of button. How can I get this to work in asp.net??? Please guide me .. Thank you

Comment: @zgood would you kindly guide me how can i work with jquery elements in this ..

Comment: Reference the jQuery script before the bootstrap ones... the bootstrap.js will probably have a dependency on jQuery.

Comment: @DotNetHaggis just tried but with no luck .. I am totally stuck on it.

Comment: In order for the nav bar to toggle you do realise that you have to reduce the width of your browser window don't you?  Have you tried this?  Then you should see the menu items disappear and then the three line menu item appear...

Comment: @DotNetHaggis exactly sir I resized and those three lines came but when i clicked on them nothing happened ?

Comment: Updated my answer below - remove the reference to the bootstrap.min.js script... see below.

Comment: @DotNetHaggis changed , with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Check the dev tools (IE, Chrome etc) that's available by default within the browser and see if there are any script errors...

Comment: @DotNetHaggis I just checked i am using Chroome error in console is Failed to load the resource http://localhost:3991/~/Scripts/bootstrap.js ? ?

Comment: @DotNetHaggis thanks i just checked path was wrong it must be <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: Yes that's exactly it - I just said that in my updated answer and explained a little.

Comment: Could you mark my post as the answer please.  That would be appreciated.

Comment: @DotNetHaggis, you saved the day. one needs to load the jquery script before bootstrap script. because of the dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to reference jQuery before Bootstrap like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE 2

The problem is with your script reference.  Remove the "~".  When directly in a script element the page doesn't understand "~".

The ~ refers to the root of the project understood by c# code.  Not html elements.

So it should be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE

You are referencing both the minified version of bootstrap.js and the full version.  Remove the:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I wonder if they are conflicting.